# How to make a event listener in nuxeo IDE

Tags: java, event-listener, nuxeo

I want to schedule an event in nuxeo IDE but I am getting the error java.lang.ClassCastException:

> org.nuxeo.ecm.core.event.impl.EventContextImpl cannot be cast to
>   org.nuxeo.ecm.core.event.impl.DocumentEventContext.

**My scheduler contribution is:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<component name="org.nuxeo.sample.ScheduleCall" version="1.0">
<extension target="org.nuxeo.ecm.core.scheduler.SchedulerService"
 point="schedule">
 <schedule id="testschedule">
 <username>Administrator</username>
 <eventId>user_created</eventId>
 <eventCategory>default</eventCategory>

 <cronExpression>0 1 * * * ?</cronExpression>
 </schedule>
 </extension>  

</component>
```

**My listener contribution is:**

```
<component name="org.nuxeo.sample.listener.contrib.ScheduleListener">

  <extension target="org.nuxeo.ecm.core.event.EventServiceComponent"
    point="listener">

    <listener name="schedulelistener" async="false" postCommit="true"
      class="org.nuxeo.sample.ScheduleListener" priority="140">
      <event>user_created</event>
    </listener>
  </extension>

</component>
```

**My java class for listener is:**

```
/**
 * 
 */

package org.nuxeo.sample;

import org.nuxeo.ecm.core.event.EventListener;
import org.nuxeo.ecm.core.event.Event;





/**
 * @author Parul.Puri01
 */


public class ScheduleListener implements EventListener {

    public void handleEvent(Event event){
        try{
            if(event!=null && event.getName().equals("user_created")){
                System.out.println("parul");
            }
            System.out.println("not an event");
       }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();

        }


    }

}
```

**The error is :**

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.nuxeo.ecm.core.event.impl.EventContextImpl cannot be cast to org.nuxeo.ecm.core.event.impl.DocumentEventContext
    at org.nuxeo.ecm.user.center.profile.localeProvider.UserLocaleSelectorListener.handleEvent(UserLocaleSelectorListener.java:43)
    at org.nuxeo.ecm.core.event.impl.EventServiceImpl.fireEvent(EventServiceImpl.java:200)
    at org.nuxeo.ecm.core.scheduler.EventJob.execute(EventJob.java:119)
    at org.nuxeo.ecm.core.scheduler.EventJob.execute(EventJob.java:65)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573)
2016-06-02 12:13:01,047 WARN  [Nuxeo-Work-default-3] [org.nuxeo.ecm.platform.ec.notification.NotificationEventListener] Can not handle notification on a event that is not bound to a DocumentEventContext
```

Please let me know how to create the listener extension point in nuxeo IDE. I am creating it as a document listener. How to resolve the error?

Answer (score 2):

The ***user_created*** eventId is internally used by the Nuxeo platform within a Document context.

You therefore cannot fire this same event with a scheduler which has no Document context.

If you want to make your sample work, just rename ***user_created*** into ***my_user_created*** or whatever.

Best,

Comment: hi, I tried this but facing the same error, can you help with the error

Comment: hi again, I personally tested your sample and it works fine for me. Your cronExpression (0 1 * * * ?) means every hour at first minute of the hour **e.g. 16h01, 17h01, 18h01, etc.** which does not match the time stamp of your log (**2016-06-02 12:13:01,047**) which leads me to think the stack is not related to your scheduler but something else.

Comment: hi, thanks a lot.. my nuxeo wasn't configured..now its done so this error doesn't persist..but I am unable to get any output..can you please provide me with the information if you are creating the scheduler as nuxeo component and the listener as document listener.. also do you see the output on your eclipse window? Your help is appreciated